# what does this regular expression in python mean (.+?)

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I saw this regular expression being used in a program - (.+?)
But I don't understand What does this mean. 
I know that,
. is for any character except newline
+ is for one or more characters
? is for zero or one character

But don't understand what this entire regex (.+?) convey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parenthesis mean a [*capturing group*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping). The `.+` would match any character *1 or more times*. The `?` makes it work in a [*non-greedy*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) fashion.

Study [Regular Expression How To](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) - it covers all of the parts of this regular expression.

This expression alone does not make much sense, and is usually a part of an expression, sample:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Hello, World!"
>>> re.match(r"(.+?), World!", s).group(1)
'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.+?
```

is any character `.` besides for new line potentially multiple times, but as fewest times as possible.

For example, say you has a regular expression that matches `(.+?)a` and you pass in

```
aba
```

then `ab`, or multiple characters in this case, will be in the capturing group in order to be able to match the `a` at the end after at least one character.

Answer (score -1):

As you said `.` is for any character so `.+` will be a series of characters matching 0 or more times and adding a `?` will make it work whether the pattern exists or does not exists.